# Issue with archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64) in C

Tags: c++, c, macos, makefile

When I run make on this program I am trying to build, I get these warnings:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ../lib/libiptools.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: ignoring file ../lib/libmpeg.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

And then it obviously fails to compile with this:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [iptool] Error 1
```

I am just having a hard time figuring out how to alter my make file and compile properly for this as I am unfamiliar with archives. Any advice is appreciate since I am sure I am missing something simple. I am using Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: Why don't you post the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

libiptools.a and libmpeg.a are compiled for 32-bit, but the rest of your project is compiled for 64-bit. Either find 64-bit versions of those libraries, or compile for 32-bit.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but how do I change my make file to compile for 32 bit?

Comment: Since you are on OS X, I assume you are compiling with clang. I don't have any expirience with clang. But try to compile with `-arch i386` and remove any reference to `-arch x86_64`