# Cannot use C libraries compiled from Go code using "Go build"

Tags: c, go

I am trying to get a minimal example of using Go code in C to work, such as [this](https://blog.filippo.io/building-python-modules-with-go-1-5/). I am struggling with the following compilation error message:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/username/gocode/src/example/example.dylib, file was built for
>   archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64):
>   /Users/username/gocode/src/example/example.dylib

My attempt is the following. I have a simple Go package in a file main.go:

```
package example

import "C"

//export GoEcho
func GoEcho(s *C.char) string {
    return C.GoString(s)
}

func main() {}
```

which I then compile using either

```
go build -buildmode=c-archive -o example.dylib main.go
```

or

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o example.dylib main.go
```

or

```
GOARCH=amd64 go build -buildmode=c-shared -o LibraryLinkExamples.dylib main.go
```

The operating system is OS X 10.11 and the the Go version is, as `go version` puts it, `go1.9 darwin/amd64`.

The C code I'm using is the following:

```
#include "example.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    GoString res = GoEcho("test");
    printf("%.*s\n", (int)res.n, res.p);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting the "which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)" error message when I am building the library and using it on the same operating system, even the computer? What can explain this?

**Update**
In the official documentation [here](https://golang.org/doc/install/source) it says:

> amd64 (also known as x86-64)

meaning it **should** be x86-64 compatible with this setting. That it isn't is possibly a bug in `go build`?

Comment: According to the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500923/issue-with-archive-which-is-not-the-architecture-being-linked-x86-64-in-c), you may have a bitness issue.  They may have been built on the same machine, but the default bitness may not be the same for each tool chain.

Comment: @jwdonahue The "tool chain" is Go build and Xcode, on the same machine. I don't see any reason why there should be a difference.

Comment: I'll just sit in the corner and rust.

Comment: @jwdonahue You may be right and I will investigate it, I was just surprised. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @jwdonahue I have updated with a new attempt where I use `GOARCH=amd64` to specify the architecture. If I understand it correctly, amd64 is x86_64 (it was originally called x86-64 but was later rebranded amd64.) However, it still does not work.

Comment: If GOARCH defaults to amd64, your test doesn't tell us anything.  Did you also try x86?

Comment: @jwdonahue The possible ones are "386", "amd64", "amd64p32", "arm", "arm64", "mips", "mipsle", "mips64", "mips64le", "ppc64", "ppc64le" and "s390x". However, I have seen it being explicitly mentioned that it works on x86, which is why I started to look into aliases, and e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601553/what-is-the-difference-between-x86-64-amd64-and-64-bit) answer says that amd64 is x86.

Comment: then use 386, that's definitely 32 bit.

Comment: @jwdonahue It doesn't work, but why do you think I should try compiling to 32 bit? I don't see anything which indicates that I need to do that. x86-64 which I try to link to is 64 bit. The problem in the question you linked to is that OP had tried to use a library compiled by someone else for 32 bit, in code which he compiled as 64 bit. I am compiling both my library and my code as 64 bit, it's not the same thing.

Comment: FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#AMD64 explains exactly what is meant by x86-64 and amd64. Both are clearly 64 bit.  This is the norm for modern systems, but many tool chains still default to 32 bit instruction sets. 32 bit code often runs faster, even on 64 bit machines, takes less memory/disk and runs on more platforms than 64 bit programs.

Comment: The error message you are getting states that example.dylib "_was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked..._".  So you've got an architecture mismatch. Delete all of the build outputs and rebuild everything for an explicit architecture.  Do not rely on the defaults.

Comment: @jwdonahue That is what I did in my third example, where I specified `GOARCH=amd64`. I added an update to the post where I linked to where it says in the official documentation that amd64 and x86-64 are the same. I cannot explain this in any other way than that there is a bug in Go's compiler.